CacheEvict is not clearing values from Hazelcast cluster
My problem involves clearing a cache provided by Hazelcast. I have two Java microservices. One is just a basic Java application that creates a Hazelcast cluster that runs on host 127.0.0.1 at the default port 5701.
The second is a Spring Boot microservice with a series of REST APIs. I want to store the results of the API calls in a Hazelcast cache. So I have created an XML file in the project that will be used to connect to the Hazelcast cluster that is running on the same machine (service name: my-cache-service)
The problem I have is that whenever I call an API that evicts the cache using the @CacheeEvict annotation, no errors are thrown but the cache is never evicted unless I restart the my-cache-service.
Where am I going wrong?
Hazelcast Configuration XML
<hazelcast-client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
                    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-client-config-4.2.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
    <cluster-name>my-hazelcast-cluster-name</cluster-name>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>localhost</address>
            <address>localhost:5701</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <kubernetes enabled="false">
            <namespace>my-namespace</namespace>
            <service-name>my-cache-service</service-name>
        </kubernetes>
    </network>
</hazelcast-client>

I am configuring my caching behaviour in the project using the following configuration class
Spring Bean for Caching Configuration
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ClientConfig clientConfig() throws IOException {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new XmlClientConfigBuilder(<the XML file specified above>).build();
        return clientConfig;
    }

    @Bean(name = "myHazelcastInstance")
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

}

I then create a bean that creates a HazelcastInstance object that successfully connects to the local cluster
HazelcastInstance Bean
@Component
@Slf4j
public class HazelcastClient {

    @Autowired
    private HazelcastInstance myHazelcastInstance;

    public IMap<String, String> getCacheMap() {
        return authHazelcast.getMap("blah-data");
    }

}

This is my service class where I have a method that should evict the contents of the cache
Service Bean
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyServiceImpl {

    private final HazelcastClient hazelcastClient;

    public void addToCache(final String key, final String value) {
        Map<String, String> map = retrieveMap();
        map.put(key, value);
        log.debug("Added key: {} value: {} to cache", key, value);
    }


    public Object getFromCache(final String key) {
        String value = retrieveMap().get(key);

        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(value)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No value found for key: " + key);
        }
        log.debug("Got key: {} value: {} from cache", key, value);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeFromCache(final String key) {
        retrieveMap().remove(key);
        evictFromCache(key);
        log.debug("Removed key: {} from cache", key);
    }

//TODO (This is the part that is not working)
@Caching(evict = {
            @CacheEvict(value = "blah-data", key = "#p0")
    })
    public void evictFromCache(final String key) {
        log.warn("Evicted key: {} from cache", key);
    }

    private ConcurrentMap<String, String> retrieveMap() {
        return hazelcastClient.getCacheMap();
    }
}


I am guessing that you are missing a dependency. First you need to add this dependency. This dependency will configure Spring to use Hazelcast as cache backend.
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>

This dependency looks for hazelcast-client.xml file automatically. You may put this file to src/main/resources path. If you need to use another file name, manual bean configuration is also ok. Just change it like below
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ClientConfig clientConfig() throws IOException {
    var xmlClientConfigBuilder = new XmlClientConfigBuilder("client.xml");
    return xmlClientConfigBuilder.build();
  }
}

Then your controller should be something like this
@GetMapping(path = "/findById/{id}")
// Setting sync to true means that consecutive hits which happened 
// before the cache was properly populated,
// will wait for the cache to actually be populated, 
// instead of performing another request to the database.
@Cacheable(key = "#id", sync = true)
public EmployeeDTO findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
 ...
}


@GetMapping(path = "/evictFromCache/{id}")
// beforeInvocation attribute allows us to control the eviction process,
// enabling us to choose whether the eviction
// should occur before or after the method execution.
@CacheEvict(key = "#id", beforeInvocation = true)
public void evictFromCache(@PathVariable Long id) {
  log.warn("Evicted key: {} from cache", id);
}

You can use this docker-compose.yaml for testing
version: '3.9'
services:
  hazelcast:
    container_name: hazelcast
    ports:
      - '5701:5701'
    image: 'hazelcast/hazelcast:5.4.0'
    environment:
      HZ_JET_ENABLED: 'true'
      HZ_JET_RESOURCEUPLOADENABLED: 'true'
  
  # http://localhost:9090
  management-center:
    image: 'hazelcast/management-center:5.4.0'
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    environment:
      - MC_DEFAULT_CLUSTER=dev
      - MC_DEFAULT_CLUSTER_MEMBERS=hazelcast


Go to http://localhost:9090 and check if the management center shows that the employee Map size changes after hitting findById and evictFromCache endpoints

I have implemented the suggested changes but now have encountered a different error that is thrown when the cache is queried
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.mypackage.MyResponse (
java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.mypackage.MyResponse is in unnamed module of loader 'app'
)
The MyResponse class is implementing Serializable interface

You probably have IMap<String, String>but trying to cast it to MyResponse somehow
